# Mysql Workbench where I can see rows count

Tags: mysql-workbench

I start using Mysql Workbench. Before I used PhpMyAdmin which shows me all rows count in  table automaticaly on select. Can somebody tell me please where I can find all rows count in table in Workbench after select?
[image]

Comment: Have you try: `select count(1) from tablename;`?

Comment: No I would like to see it on default. And it is there as answer below shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Messages column in the Ouput pane shows resulting rowcount for each statement execution. Scroll down to the bottom or sort by the Time column desc to see the latest result.

[image: rowcounts]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not see that :)

Comment: You're very welcome!